# Auto-collapse any item in PrimeFaces PanelMenu on page loading

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm writing a Primefaces 5.1 portlet.

It consists in a unique page containing a `panelMenu`, and I need that it starts with any panel collapsed everytime a user change page (on page loading).

But, if I open a panel, then change page, it will start showing that panel still opened.

I wasn't able to find any option to achieve this goal (e.g. collapsed=true, ignoreCookie=true or something similar).

The only solution I found was the following Javascript code:

```
PrimeFaces.widgets.myPanelMenu.collapseRootSubmenu(PrimeFaces.widgets.myPanelMenu.headers);
```

The problem is that this code will collapse any opened panel (so on page loading user is able to see panel menu collapsing animation) but it seems it doesn't store this state in its cookie/localstorage... the result is that on any page loading user can see this animation.

I'm sure it doesn't save its state, because the only way to "solve" the problem is to manually re-open and re-collapse the panels... then, on following page change, these menus start closed (and there is no animation).

I also tried to use `PrimeFaces.widgets.sideMenuPanel.saveState()` after collapsing, but with no success.

Do you have any idea about?

Thank you...

Comment: Tried a newer PF version?

Comment: And then take a look at the [source of both the old (5.1)](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.js#L1305) and new (5.3 snapshot) and create a patch in the js

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, but I'm not speaking about a bug... I just need for a specific (not default) behaviour, and I don't know if an official way to achieve it exists.

Comment: I'm not speaking about a bug either. I'm speaking about improvements that were made in newer releases. You can read that in releasenotes/blogs/issuelists/documentation etc... If you notice these improvements you can look how it was implemented and create a workaround... Easy... That is the advantage of open source.

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't understand the usefulness of your asnwer. I'm here (and any question on this site is here) to ask "if a way to achieve a desidred behaviour exist": I'm conscious about oper surce advantages, but I'm searching the solution for a programming problem, not a suggestion to which open project I need to contribute :)

Comment: I'm not talking about contributing... I nowhere stated that. I'm talking about investigating if it already **is** implemented in a **newer** PrimeFaces version and then create a patch for **your** version. In newer versions you can explicitly set an attribute to **not** restore the state or restore it even across multiple pages

Comment: Ah, ok... I just now understand what you mean... but this behaviour doesn't exist nor in latest version.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/121 Setting it to false should not keep the state for 5.2.1/5.1.16 and up (so also 5.3-SNAPSHOT or the RC1/2 releases)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you, I didn't see that

Comment: You see this behaviour **does** exist in latest version ;-). Keeping track of blogs, releasenotes etc when you use some framework or scan the fourm or stackoverflow from time to time helps...

Comment: Yes you're right... :) By the way (for project needs) I can't change version of library, nor modify the code...  :( so, because my version doens't support it yet, I'm moving to a client side solution to make a quick fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

If you read my discussion with Kukeltje (comments on my question), you will find that latest Primefaces' versions will solve the problem.

Otherwise, if you want to avoid upgrade or modify sources, and you need a quick fix based on Javascript only please read the following part of the answer.

It directly works on the component's state using JavaScript.

First of all you need to have a variable reference to your component:

```
<p:panelMenu model="#{menuBackingBean.menuModel}" widgetVar="sidePanelMenu" />
```

Then you should add the following JS code on document ready:

```
                var panelMenu = PrimeFaces.widgets.sidePanelMenu;
                // 1. On page loading collapses possible opened panels
                panelMenu.collapseRootSubmenu(panelMenu.headers);
                // following line is commented because it never should be necessary is not necessary (unless unexpected situation I never verified)
                //clearSidePanelMenuPreferences();
                // 2. Call the "clear preferences" actions on click on two tpe of links: first level are the panel link (used to open/close the menu) and second level are the destination links
                // We need to fork also on the first level links to be sure it works after user clicks there then exit from the page in another way
                panelMenu.headers.children("a").click(function(){setTimeout(clearSidePanelMenuPreferences, 500)}); // setTimeout is necessary because this event should be fired after preferences are written
                panelMenu.headers.siblings().find("a").click(function(){clearSidePanelMenuPreferences();});
```

The function called to clear preferences are the following:

```
        function clearSidePanelMenuPreferences() {
            var panelMenu = PrimeFaces.widgets.sidePanelMenu;
            panelMenu.expandedNodes = [];   // clear the opened panels lists
            panelMenu.saveState();          // store this information
        }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please check this block of code

```
PF('myPanelMenu').headers.each(
                function(){
                    var header = jQuery(this);                     
                          PF('myPanelMenu').collapseRootSubmenu(header);
                          header.removeClass('ui-state-hover');                     
                }
            );
```

Comment: Please add some descriptive text.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to do this in order to execute this method only once and keep the menu option selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(location.pathname == "/cotizador/" || location.pathname == "/cotizador/faces/login.xhtml"){
    var panelMenu = PrimeFaces.widgets.sidePanelMenu;

    // 1. On page loading collapses possible opened panels
    panelMenu.collapseRootSubmenu(panelMenu.headers);
    panelMenu.expandedNodes = [];   // clear the opened panels lists
    panelMenu.saveState();
 }   
});
```

Comment: I think this copies a part of the solution I proposed, but it is not ok 1) you hardcoded the paths (and, generally speaking, it is not a good idea for a portlet) .. 2) it doesn't work if user opens a panel and then exits from the page in a different way (e.g. by refreshing)